# Give the hyperlinks in the revision history a little breathing room, they're suffocating!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, revisions-list

With the addition of the "link" uhh link to the row of hyperlinks in the revision history, it has pointed my eyes to the lack of space they are given in that row. It's almost the same as the links seen below every post, except those ones have additional padding around them which is also clickable, whereas these links are *just* links. Can they be formatted similar to the post options to make them easier to click on and not look so pushed together, especially compared to the big Markdown view buttons below?

> [image]

Comment: FHRSpeechBubble. _likes_

Comment: Make the Markdown view buttons smaller instead. I see little enough of the post in /review anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Making the Markdown buttons smaller may improve things, but not the fact that the hyperlinks are squished together and inconvenient to click upon.

Comment: I hope link links aren't related to like likes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The revision menus are now given the same CSS treatment as the post menus, so the spacing, colors, etc. should match now.

> [image]